# If column A value in dict key, set column B to dict value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':['A','A','B','C'],'b':[1,2,3,4]})
   a  b
0  A  1
1  A  2
2  B  3
3  C  4
```

and a dictionary that looks like this:

```
convert={'A':9,'C':8}
```

If column `a` has a value in `convert`'s keys then the corresponding row for column `b` should be changed to the dict value. This way the output would look like:

```
   a  b
0  A  9
1  A  9
2  B  3
3  C  8
```

I was thinking something along the lines of this (does not work):

```
pd.np.where(df['a'].isin(convert),convert[df['a']],df['b'])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map` with `fillna`; `df.a.map(convert)` maps values in column *a* to corresponding values in the dict if key exists otherwise `NaN`, then use `fillna(df.b)` to fill missing values with values from column *b*:

```
df['b'] = df.a.map(convert).fillna(df.b)

df
#   a     b
#0  A   9.0
#1  A   9.0
#2  B   3.0
#3  C   8.0
```